# Reg Export Document Location Path

Tags: batch, script, cmd.exe, windows-registry, export

```
@echo on

reg export "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Personal" C:\%username%.reg

pause
```

I wrote this simple batch to just copy the reg of shell folders. The folder obviously exist because I can see it, but it says invalid path when trying to run it.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- `Personal` is the name of a *value* inside the key of
  `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`,
  while the
  [reg export](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-export)
  command expects a key-name.
- The root folder of `C:\` is protected against writes.

The correct syntax is:

```
reg export "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" C:\some-folder\%username%.reg
```